# Varnish 503 Error on magento "success" page

Tags: magento, checkout, varnish, http-status-code-503

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 with Varnish.
on checkout completion magento should redirect to index/success/ but instead i get a varnish **503 GURU MEDITATION Error**.

Checkout Extension: IWD OnepageCheckout

### Settings i have tried so far:

**pipe checkout pages:**

```
if (req.url ~ "^/(checkout|onepagecheckout)"){return(pipe);}
```

**Increase Timeout and http header size:**

```
- Connection Timeout: 1,5
- First Byte Timeout : 60
- Between Bytes Timeout: 60
- Send Timeout: 60
- http header Size: 64000
```

### This is the Varnish log:

```
   15 TxRequest    b POST
   15 TxURL        b /onepagecheckout/index/saveOrder/
   15 TxProtocol   b HTTP/1.1
   15 TxHeader     b Host: www.shop.com
   15 TxHeader     b Content-Length: 1021
   15 TxHeader     b Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
   15 TxHeader     b X-Prototype-Version: 1.7
   15 TxHeader     b Origin: https://www.shop.com
   15 TxHeader     b X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
   15 TxHeader     b User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
   15 TxHeader     b Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   15 TxHeader     b Referer: https://www.shop.com/onepagecheckout
   15 TxHeader     b Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
   15 TxHeader     b X-Forwarded-Port: 443
   15 TxHeader     b X-Forwarded-For: 80.171.183.169
   15 TxHeader     b Accept-Encoding: gzip
   15 TxHeader     b Cookie: EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE=1; frontend=13a7s71obc2u4t5ei4np4b076b3up6uo
   15 TxHeader     b X-Varnish: 518358516
   15 BackendClose b r4011ssl
   11 SessionOpen  c 80.171.183.169 47078 0.0.0.0:8000
   11 ReqStart     c 80.171.183.169 47078 518358516
   11 RxRequest    c POST
   11 RxURL        c /onepagecheckout/index/saveOrder/
   11 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   11 RxHeader     c Host: www.shop.com
   11 RxHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
   11 RxHeader     c Content-Length: 1021
   11 RxHeader     c Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
   11 RxHeader     c X-Prototype-Version: 1.7
   11 RxHeader     c Origin: https://www.shop.com
   11 RxHeader     c X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
   11 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
   11 RxHeader     c Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   11 RxHeader     c Referer: https://www.shop.com/onepagecheckout
   11 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
   11 RxHeader     c Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
   11 RxHeader     c Cookie: EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE=1; __utma=26003752.1013074055.1392134206.1392134206.1392134206.1; __utmb=26003752.36.10.1392134206; __utmc=26003752; __utmz=26003752.1392134206.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); frontend=13a7s71obc2u4t5ei4np4b076
   11 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-Port: 443
   11 VCL_call     c recv pass
   11 VCL_call     c hash
   11 Hash         c /onepagecheckout/index/saveOrder/
   11 Hash         c www.shop.com
   11 VCL_return   c hash
   11 VCL_call     c pass pass
   11 Backend      c 12 r4011ssl r4011ssl
   11 FetchError   c Resource temporarily unavailable
   11 FetchError   c backend write error: 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
   11 Backend      c 15 r4011ssl r4011ssl
   11 FetchError   c Resource temporarily unavailable
   11 FetchError   c backend write error: 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
   11 VCL_call     c error deliver
   11 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
   11 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   11 TxStatus     c 503
   11 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
   11 TxHeader     c Server: Varnish
   11 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   11 TxHeader     c Retry-After: 5
   11 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 418
   11 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
   11 TxHeader     c Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 17:00:46 GMT
   11 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 518358516
   11 TxHeader     c Age: 10
   11 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
   11 TxHeader     c Connection: close
   11 Length       c 418
   11 ReqEnd       c 518358516 1392138036.718916416 1392138046.719257116 0.000075340 10.000248671 0.000092030
   11 SessionClose c error
```

Comment: Why would you need special treatment for this page, assuming cart pages use cookies, varnish should `return(pass)` and this would be handled totally from the backend

Comment: If you are asking why i set varnish to pipe the checkout: 

This is not exactly related to the 503 error but to another possible problem when logging in on the checkout page.
See: [Magento Onepagechekout login issue when using Varnish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876529/magento-onepagechekout-login-issue-when-using-varnish)

Comment: You have a `return(pass)` directive prior to the pipe one (I bet you are checking request method POST). So your Pipe is not taking effect. I'll try also to rise Connection Timeout.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?